# How to group and aggregate data starting from constant and ending on changing date?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to aggregate data between constant date, like first day of year, and all the other dates through the year. There are two variants of this problem:

easier - sum:

```
created_at   value
01-01-2012       5
02-01-2012       6
05-01-2012       1
05-01-2012       1

01-02-2012       3
02-02-2012       2
05-02-2012       1
```

which should output:

```
Date             Month to date sum     Year to date sum
01-01-2012       5                     5
02-01-2012       11                    11
05-01-2012       13                    13
01-02-2012       3                     14
02-02-2012       5                     15
05-02-2012       6                     16
```

and harder - count unique:

```
created_at   value
01-01-2012       a
02-01-2012       b
05-01-2012       c
05-01-2012       c

01-02-2012       a
02-02-2012       a
05-02-2012       d
```

which should output:

```
Date             Month to date unique  Year to date unique
01-01-2012       1                     1
02-01-2012       2                     2
05-01-2012       3                     3
01-02-2012       1                     3
02-02-2012       1                     3
05-02-2012       2                     4
```

The data is, of course, in Pandas data frame.The obvious, but very clumsy way is to create for loop between the starting dates and the moving one. The problem looks like a popular one. Is there some reasonable pandas builtin way for such type of computation? Regarding counting unique I also want to avoid stacking lists, as I have large number of rows and unique values.

I was checking out Pandas window functions, but it doesn't look like a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `groupby`:

###### Cumulative sum:

```
df["created_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df["created_at"], format="%d-%m-%Y")

df["Month to date sum"] = df.groupby(df["created_at"].dt.month)["value"].transform('cumsum')
df["Year to date sum"] = df.groupby(df["created_at"].dt.year)["value"].transform('cumsum')

>>> df
  created_at  value  Month to date sum  Year to date sum
0 2012-01-01      5                  5                 5
1 2012-01-02      6                 11                11
2 2012-01-05      1                 12                12
3 2012-02-01      3                  3                15
4 2012-02-02      2                  5                17
5 2012-02-05      1                  6                18
```

###### Cumulative unique count:

```
df2["created_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["created_at"], format="%d-%m-%Y")
df2["Month to date unique"] = df2.groupby(df2["created_at"].dt.month)["value"].apply(lambda x: (~x.duplicated()).cumsum())
df2["Year to date unique"] = df2.groupby(df2["created_at"].dt.year)["value"].apply(lambda x: (~x.duplicated()).cumsum())

>>> df2
  created_at value  Month to date unique  Year to date unique
0 2012-01-01     a                     1                    1
1 2012-01-02     b                     2                    2
2 2012-01-05     c                     3                    3
3 2012-02-01     a                     1                    3
4 2012-02-02     a                     1                    3
5 2012-02-05     d                     2                    4
```

Comment: This approach works as long as there is only one row per one date in input. When there are more, it gives one output per row and added to previous df raises ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. To be honest I don't understand yet what it yields. 

I'm modifying the question so it includes doubling row on a date.

Comment: It works for the input you provided. Like I said, your question needs more focus. One question per post. Also you can't define "month-to-date" sum if you have two values for one date. Unless they include different times.

Comment: But the point is not aggregating by row but by date, so it shouldn't matter how many records per date there are. Do you suggest creating two separate questions out of this one?